# USB Device error: "unable to enumerate device"

Tags: usb, sound, interface

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell 3442 laptop. I'm trying to make an audio interface - Tascam US-800 - to work. I've done it before years ago, same hardware, can't remember what Ubuntu Studio version.. Now I'm getting this kind of error. I just dumped Windows out of my system, tried first Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and now Ubuntu 18.04, with no success. The same device was running Ok on Windows 10 a few days ago. Tried again in my wife's laptop with Windows - working fine.

I'm getting this error in `dmesg`:

```
[  580.230758] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[  580.646801] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -32
[  580.646910] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[  581.250887] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[  581.330909] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  581.518927] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  581.706957] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  581.786972] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  581.974997] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  582.083205] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Strange thing is, when I tried with a Live version of Ubuntu from a flash drive, I get a different kind of error:

```
[11386.135043] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[11386.253453] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 4 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 
0x4 has invalid maxpacket 64
[11386.253462] usb 3-1: config 1 interface 4 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 
0x85 has invalid maxpacket 64
[11386.253817] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0644, idProduct=802a
[11386.253820] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=12, Product=13, 
SerialNumber=0
[11386.253822] usb 3-1: Product: US-800
[11386.253824] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: TASCAM
[11386.748068] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 
0x101, wIndex = 0x1e00, type = 4
[11386.748075] usb 3-1: 30:0: cannot get min/max values for control 1 
(id 30)
[11386.831499] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 
0x201, wIndex = 0x1e00, type = 4
[11386.831510] usb 3-1: 30:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 
(id 30)
[11386.912375] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 
0x301, wIndex = 0x1e00, type = 4
[11386.912386] usb 3-1: 30:0: cannot get min/max values for control 3 
(id 30)
[11387.005003] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 
0x401, wIndex = 0x1e00, type = 4
[11387.005022] usb 3-1: 30:0: cannot get min/max values for control 4 
(id 30)
[11387.080115] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 
0x501, wIndex = 0x1e00, type = 4
[11387.080123] usb 3-1: 30:0: cannot get min/max values for control 5 
(id 30)
```

I've tried several things like `usbcore.autosuspend=-1`, `iommu=soft`, the "unplug everything for 3 min" trick, ... plugged/unplugged in every USB hub, all of them work fine with other devices like optical mouse. I'm googling everything related to this problem with no success... I don't want to give up, because as I said it worked before... and going back to Windows is a big turn off for me.

EDIT1: I forgot to say this is a device not officially supported by Ubuntu or Tascam, which has discontinued the product. There are official drivers for Windows and Mac. Please, point me to the way of hacking those drivers!

EDIT2: So I did a clean install of Ubuntu Studio 19.10, this time letting it erase everything from disk and partition it's own way. Now I get only the second error, `cannot get ctl value`. That's a start.. I'm going to research more on the subject. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: I know Wine can't run hardware, but I wonder if there is a wrapper for the win driver?... On the other hand, the Mac driver is just an application with no installation involved. Is there a way to run it on Ubuntu? I'm really a complete begginner in the Linux / programming world.. But if I know there IS a way, i'm putting effort to try it

Answer (score 0):

Heads up - for me, this was caused by having my USB drive plugged into a USB3 port on an ESXi server. The device was passed through into the virtual machine connected to a virtual *USB2* controller. That was the problem. Deleting the device and controller and re-configuring as USB3 resolved.